# Nesting a WHILE loop within a SELECT

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to extract some data out of an EDMS document management system using T-SQL.  Basically I need to create a report that lists all the documents on the system and the file path to each one of them. The "docs" table has one row for each document held with docid as the key.  Here's an example:

| docid | size | ext |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 1 | jpg |
| 10002 | 1 | png |
| 10003 | 1 | tif |
| 10004 | 3 | tif |

The filename of the associated doc is normally the docid followed by the extension, however because a document in the form of a tif scan can be across several individual files a suffix is added for tif files consisting of an underscore followed by the part number (the size column indicates how many parts exist for each scan.)  So for the above example I would need to output the following:

| docid | filepath |
| --- | --- |
| 10001 | c:\documents\10001.jpg |
| 10002 | c:\documents\10002.png |
| 10003 | c:\documents\10003_1.tif |
| 10004 | c:\documents\10004_1.tif |
| 10004 | c:\documents\10004_2.tif |
| 10004 | c:\documents\10004_3.tif |

I figure it needs a WHILE loop nested within a SELECT somehow, but can't figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: What could be the maximum value for `size`? Also, a `WHILE` is the *last* thing you want here; SQL is a set based language and so excels at set based solutions, but is awful at iterative ones.

Comment: Why does 10003 have a `_1` but the first two do no?

Comment: I *assume* the OP only wants to part numbers for `tif` files, @GordonLinoff .

Comment: Yep, the part numbers only apply to tif files. So tif files always have the part number (even if there's only one part), but other file extensions always only have a single part with no suffix added. Blame the EDMS designers; I don't think I would've designed it this way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming* that `size` can't be a value greater than `10`, you could use a `VALUES` table construct to create the extra rows:

```sql
SELECT YT.docid,
       CONCAT(N'C:\documents\',YT.docid,CASE YT.ext WHEN 'tif' THEN CONCAT(N'_',V.I) END,N'.',YT.ext) AS FilePath
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))V(I) ON YT.Size >= V.I;
```

If you could have much larger values, then you could instead use an inline tally, or even an existing Tally Table you have on your instance.

*Worth noting, the reason I use a Tally is because they are* significantly *faster than an rCTE. Even for a small amount of rows there are performance benefits to using the set based method of a Tally over the iterative method of the rCTE.*

---

It seems that the OP could have large numbers. As I mentioned, therefore, use an inline Tally, or a Tally Table you have on your instance. An inline tally would look like this:

```sql
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(size) FROM dbo.YourTable)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3) --Up to 1000. Add more cross joins for more rows
SELECT YT.docid,
       CONCAT(N'C:\documents\',YT.docid,CASE YT.ext WHEN 'tif' THEN CONCAT(N'_',T.I) END,N'.',YT.ext) AS FilePath
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN Tally T ON YT.Size >= T.I
```

Comment: I just checked and unfortunately in a few cases it goes higher than a single digit (three of them go to ten parts and another one goes to fourteen parts.)  This is just for the records I need to extract, which are a subset of the whole table; some go much higher than fourteen but it so happens I'm not interested in those.

Comment: Then add more values to the `VALUES` construct, @IanW . Or, as I mention use an inline Tally. You never answered  my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67019445/nesting-a-while-loop-within-a-select/67019518#comment118464009_67019445) on the max values for `size`, so I had to guess it wouldn't be large.

Comment: I've demonstrated an inline tally for you as well, @IanW .

Comment: Sorry answered the question in reply to someone else but not to you specifically, apologies.  OK I'm trying your inline tally now but I'm getting "The multi-part identifier "V.I" could not be bound."

Comment: Ahh, I changed the alias in the latter, but missed a reference.; should be `T.I` @IanW .

Comment: Thanks, that does just what I wanted :)  Confused me a bit at first because I thought it was just doing the '_1' parts and skipping the rest.  But then I realised that the default order is to output all the' _1' parts followed by all the '_2' parts and so on.  But I can sort it after to how I need it :)

Comment: That's because there's no `ORDER BY` in the above query, @IanW, so the data engine is free to return the rows in what ever arbitrary order it "feels like". Adding an explicit `ORDER BY` will allow you to return the data in what ever order you want it in.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want using a recursive CTE:

```
with files as (
      select docid, ext, 1 as cnt, size
      from documents
      union all
      select docid, ext, cnt + 1, size
      from files
      where cnt < size
     )
select f.docid, f.ext, f.cnt,
       concat('c:\documents\', docid,
              (case when ext = 'tif' 
                    then concat('_', cnt)
                    else ''
               end), '.', ext)
from files f;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=13ce34676dde49535da014411fbcf471) is a db<>fiddle.